# Computing the received signal

Tags: communication, wireless, digital-communications

My question may seem a little bit easy but I'm new to these concepts and was hoping if you could help me clarify them by answering my questions.

The received signal at the detector writes:
$$ y = h x + n$$
where \$h\$ is the channel gain, \$x\$ is the transmit intensity being \$0\$ or \$2P\$ and \$n\$ is Gaussian with zero-mean and variance \$\sigma_n^2\$.

I want to compute the BER in BPSK modulation. My problem is how can I compute \$y\$ knowing that \$x\$ can be either \$0\$ or \$2P\$. I know how to sample from \$h\$ and \$n\$ but I don't know how to generate \$x\$.

If \$\mathbb{E}[x^2] = 2 P^2\$, does this mean that \$E_b\$, the energy per bit equal to \$2P^2\$?

Comment: BPSK should not have different power for the mark and space. Can you be more clear about what modulation format you are using?

Comment: Sorry but as I said I'm kind of beginner, I didn't understand what you mean by "different power for the mark and space". Could you explain it in simpler terms so that I can answer you. Thanks

Comment: You said "the transmit intensity being 0 or 2P". This isn't what should be happening for BPSK. BPSK should transmit the same power for 1's (marks) and 0's (spaces). Transmitting 0 power for one symbol and 2P power for the other symbol would be on-off keying (OOK).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now I understand the difference between the two type of modulation. In this case, the modulation is then OOK.